# DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER not firing

Tags: iphone, grand-central-dispatch

I'm creating a timer on the global queue, configured to fire 45 seconds from creation time but for some reason, it doesn't seem to fire at all. Changing it to fire now also doesn't do anything.

The rest app has a lot going on so there's probably something pre-empting the timer from firing.

This is how the timer is created:

```
dispatch_queue_t globalQueue = 
        dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0); 

timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, globalQueue); 
if (timer) {

// start 45 seconds for now
dispatch_time_t startTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 45ull * NSEC_PER_SEC);
uint64_t interval = 15ull * NSEC_PER_SEC; // every 15 seconds, converted to nanosecs

// leeway:8 microseconds
dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, startTime, interval, 8000ull); 

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block); // block is passed in

dispatch_resume(timer);
```

1) What's a good way to try to debug/figure out why it's not firing? If not,

2) Is there a way to list all given tasks that are scheduled to run on a queue at a specific point in time?

Some of the work done by the app can't be launched on the simulator so I need to debug over on the test device itself.

Comment: Just curious, if you change the priority to DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_NORMAL does it fire? Also, I assume you're checking that block is not NULL right?

Comment: Correct - the block is not NULL and the only time the timer fires is when it's configured with DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, which I can't have it run on. So I'm trying to figure if there's a tool to help figure out what's blocked on the low priority queue or if I just have to trace all of the code.

Comment: Is there a limit on how many items can be configured to run at low priority?

Comment: There's no special hard limit, it's based on your current system load etc. But, if you've done something that does block, like a blocking read or something, you will quickly run out of worker threads.

Comment: Yes, there are two tools that work very well. First, the low-level, terminal run sc_usage for seeing if you have threads blocked in system calls etc. You also have the Dispatch instrument which works exceptionally well exactly for this. It doesn't show up under iPhone or Simulator templates, but it works just fine. Just choose it from Mac OS X, then target your app in the simulator (you will have to have run/installed it first through xcode obviously), then hit record. It will launch your app in the simulator and it works great.

Comment: I should have clarified that there's some hardware features we rely on that's not available in the simulator so the 'Dispatch' instrument doesn't seem to be an option. As soon as I tried to select a process on the target device, the 'Record' button becomes disabled. Can sc_usage work outside of the desktop/simulator?

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes it much harder to use the system tools. sc_usage won't really work for you unless your jailbreak your device and ssh into it (and even then, I'm not sure if it works or not since I've never tried). You could use shark to take samples and see where all your processes are using time. This has the added benefit of showing you system calls you might be trapped in. Do your timers/other GCD blocks actually call blocking system calls?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. My guess is that your timer is local variable and is released just after you set things up. You could make it a class property.
Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14590774/1970912).

Answer (score 1):

Your constants need to be unsigned long longs, not unsigned longs. Change to these:

```
dispatch_time_t startTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 45ull * NSEC_PER_SEC);
uint64_t interval = 15ull * NSEC_PER_SEC; // every 15 seconds, converted to nanosecs
```