# Can't run a timer in GCD block with a dispatch_source_t in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, grand-central-dispatch

I want to create a timer in GCD block ( which will fire once every 2 seconds and call a method ) to use it as a background task. But as i see timer fires never. Here is my code:

```
- (void)startMessaging
{
    BOOL queue = YES;
    dispatch_queue_t _queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_source_t timerSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER,0,0, _queue);
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timerSource, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), 2ull * NSEC_PER_SEC,1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC );
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timerSource, ^{
        if (queue) {
            [self observeNewMsgs];
        }
    });
    dispatch_resume(timerSource);
}

- (void)observeNewMsgs
{
    NSLog(@"JUST TO TEST");
    // Staff code...
}
```

So what's a problem with this? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to make your `dispatch_source_t` a class property or instance variable, so it doesn't fall out of scope (because in ARC, when it falls out of scope, it is released). If you do that, your code will work fine, e.g.:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_source_t timerSource;
@property (getter = isObservingMessages) BOOL observingMessages;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self startMessaging];
}

- (void)startMessaging
{
    self.observingMessages = YES;
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    self.timerSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
    dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timerSource, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), 2ull * NSEC_PER_SEC, 1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.timerSource, ^{
        if (self.isObservingMessages) {
            [self observeNewMsgs];
        }
    });
    dispatch_resume(self.timerSource);
}

- (void)observeNewMsgs
{
    NSLog(@"JUST TO TEST");
    // Staff code...
}

@end
```

Also note, if you wanted the ability to change the value of your `BOOL` after the background process was initiated, you might want to make that a class property, too, as demonstrated above. I also renamed it to `observingMessages` to make its purpose more plain.

(It's just stylistic, but I only use the underscore character for class instance variables, so I renamed your `_queue` variable to be `queue`.)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I wish the GCD docs were updated to mention this.

Comment: A `dispatch_source_t` cannot be `strong` or `retain` in Xcode 7.1.1. Your code will not compile.

Comment: @Cœur - No, that's not true. If you're seeing that error, it's probably because you set compiler flag `-DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0`, which as described in `<os/object.h>`, turns off object behavior for GCD types. But I retested this in Xcode 7.1.1 (as well as Xcode 7.2 beta 3), and `strong` works fine (and, in fact, is needed).

Comment: You'll also get this error if you target OS X versions prior to 10.8 or iOS versions prior to 6, as that predates the object handling of GCD types, and thus requires manual `dispatch_retain` and `dispatch_release`.

Comment: You're right, I was targeting iOS5. Code is fine when targeting iOS6.