# Constant sync a Mobile Application with a server

Tags: android, ios, client-server, real-time

I am starting to build a mobile application (android and ios) ,
The app will need to have some "pipes" to have a constant sync with a server for a small amount of information (some kind of user settings that can be changed at any time), the end user need to get some settings from the data server all the time...

I need to understand what is the best way to approach this,
for as much a i know i can send a request to the server every 1 second but i don't believe that this is the best solution.

I am regarding a really small amount of information (200 characters)...

some kind of real time information ...

Any directions will be most welcomed.

Comment: You should maintain a constant socket connection.

Answer (score 1):

This link to a previous stackoverflow question looks to answer your question...

You would just need to place your polling code in their "Messaging" method.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14590774/2208006